# Prove that if $p$ is a prime number, then $p|n^p-n$

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

> Prove that if $p$ is a prime number, then $p|n^p − n$ for $n ≥ 1$

I tried proof by induction for this but was not able to even prove the base case (I tried it for $n=1$ since we're trying to prove for $n≥1$). I'm more used to seeing these kinds of problems with actual numbers instead of the abstract prime $p$. So what I'm understanding for this problem, it's asking me that any prime $p$ should be able to divide $n^p - n$, but isn't this false? If we let $n = 1$ and $p = 2, 2|1-1$ shouldn't be right. Can someone elaborate for me or give a few hints? I think proof by induction should be the right direction though...

Comment: This is the content of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Actually, $2$ does divide $0$ since $0=2\cdot 0$. For the general proof, as Parcly Taxel says, see Fermat's little theorem. The idea that $p\mid n^p-n$ is equivalent to $n^p\equiv n\pmod p$, which is Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: 1-1=0.  So 2|1-1 is perfectly fine.  Everything divides zero.

Comment: Proof by induction is utterly impossible.  There is no way to go from one prime to the next.

Comment: Read up on Fermats Little theorem.  If n is not a multiple of p then $n^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p $.  Or in other words $p $ will divide $n^{p-1}-1$.

Comment: @fleablood Induction over $n$ works.

Comment: Yes, but you can't do induction over $p$, which is more of the point.  And how can you possibly prove that all prime $p|2^p - 2$ or for that matter how con you prove $p|n^p - n$ then $p|(n+1)^p - (n+1)$.  Induction is really not the way to got.